# Pytorch memory model: how does "torch.from_numpy()" work?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, shared-memory

I'm trying to have an in-depth understanding of how `torch.from_numpy()` works.

```py
import numpy as np
import torch

arr = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=np.float32)
t = torch.from_numpy(arr)
print("arr: {0}\nt: {1}\n".format(arr, t))

arr[0,0]=1
print("arr: {0}\nt: {1}\n".format(arr, t))

print("id(arr): {0}\nid(t): {1}".format(id(arr), id(t)))
```

The output looks like this:

```py
arr: [[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
t: tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])

arr: [[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
t: tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])

id(arr): 2360964353040
id(t): 2360964352984
```

This is part of the doc from `torch.from_numpy()`:

> from_numpy(ndarray) -> Tensor
>
> Creates a :class:`Tensor` from a :class:`numpy.ndarray`.
>
> The returned tensor and :attr:`ndarray` **share the same memory**. Modifications to
>   the tensor will be reflected in the :attr:`ndarray` and vice versa. The returned
>   tensor is not resizable.

And this is taken from the doc of `id()`:

> Return the identity of an object.
>
> This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
>   (**CPython uses the object's memory address.**)

So here comes the question: 
Since the ndarray `arr` and tensor `t` share the same memory, why do they have different memory addresses?

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `t` and `arr` are different Python objects at different regions of memory (hence different `id`) but both point to the same memory address which contains the data (contiguous (usually) C array).

`numpy` operates on this region using `C` code binded to `Python` functions, same goes for `torch` (but using `C++`). `id()` doesn't know anything about the memory address of data itself, only of it's "wrappers".

**EDIT:** When you assign `b = a` (assuming `a` is `np.array`), both are references to the same Python wrapper (`np.ndarray`). In other words **they are the same object with different name**.

It's just how Python's assignment works, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). All of the cases below would return `True` as well:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

tensor = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
tensor2 = tensor
id(tensor) == id(tensor2)

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
arr2 = arr
id(arr) == id(arr2)

some_str = "abba"
other_str = some_str
id(some_str) == id(other_str)

value = 0
value2 = value
id(value) == id(value2)
```

Now, when you use `torch.from_numpy` on `np.ndarray` you have two objects of different classes (`torch.Tensor` and original `np.ndarray`). As those are of different types they can't have the same `id`. One could see this case as analogous to the one below:

```
value = 3
string_value = str(3)

id(value) == id(string_value)
```

Here it's intuitive both `string_value` and `value` are two different objects at different memory locations.

**EDIT 2:**

All in all concepts of Python object and underlying C array have to be separated. `id()` doesn't know about C bindings (how could it?), but it knows about memory addresses of Python structures (`torch.Tensor`, `np.ndarray`).

In case of `numpy` and `torch.tensor` you can have following situations:

- separate on Python level but using same memory region for array (`torch.from_numpy`)
- separate on Python level and underlying memory region (one `torch.tensor` and another `np.array`). Could be created by `from_numpy` followed by `clone()` or a-like deep copy operation.
- same on Python level and underlying memory region (e.g. two `torch.tensor` objects, one referencing another as provided above)

Comment: Do you mean `id ()` only knows the memory addresses of variables `arr` and `t`? However, if you create a ndarray like `a = np.array([1, 2, 3])`, then assign it to b, `b = a`, why will `id()` behave the same on them? I'm still confused, can you explain in more detail?